# select and echo a single element from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a solution for my new website. I want to echo a single link from my table.

Examples in my pictures table:

```
http://picurelinke.pl,
http://picurelinke.pl,
http://picurelinke.pl,
```

I want to echo only the first link. Some can help me?

Comment: Explode by `,` and take first element of array.

Comment: could u give me any examples?

Comment: Examples of what?

Comment: i dont get it how can i Explode by ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode it with comma(,) and take first element of it.

```
$links = 'http://testurl.com,http://testurl.com,http://testurl.com';
$linksArray = explode(',', $links);
$firstLink = $linksArray[0];
echo $firstLink;
```

Comment: Removed your links... :) it was just for demo purpose so you can understand better...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this column in `$data` variable. So you can do following.

```
$urls = explode(',', $data);
$first = isset($urls[0]) ? $urls[0] : null;
```

Comment: This same, show me all links.
  $data = 'http://picurelinke.pl,http://picurelinke.pl,http://picurelinke.pl';
  $urls = explode(',', $data);
  $first = isset($urls[0]) ? $urls[0] : null;
  echo $first;

Comment: @Lesiu I would say it is not possible :)
Try running exactly the code you sent in some online tool, like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com.

Are you sure you saved changes and you are executing correct file/version?

Comment: @Lesiu If its the same code as you mentioned - I see double semicolon here - pl.';;

Comment: @Eakethet See it too. Am surprised compiler executed that without error.

Comment: @DanielVítek its like blank space, same with {} - https://3v4l.org/p1VW6